# ag-grid: Get sorted selected rows

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid with filtering and sorting and have enabled multiple row selection. The [documentation](https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-selection/) provides a method (`getSelectedRows()`) to get the selected rows but only unsorted.
Is there another way to get the rows with the current sorting, without having to sort the data again?

```
// template

  <ag-grid-angular
    class="ag-theme-alpine data-grid" 
    [getRowId]="getRowId"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [columnTypes]="columnTypes"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [rowModelType]="rowModelType"
    [serverSideInfiniteScroll]="true"
    [pagination]="true"
    [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize"
    [cacheBlockSize]="cacheBlockSize"
    [maxBlocksInCache]="maxBlocksInCache"
    [editType]="editType"
    [rowSelection]="'multiple'"
    (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    (modelUpdated)="onModelUpdated($event)"
    (rowValueChanged)="onRowValueChanged($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>

// typescript

  onSelectionChanged() {
    console.log("selected", this.gridApi.getSelectedRows()); // this prints the unsorted data, even when sorting is applied
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
onSelectionChanged() {
  const selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();
  const selectedSortedRows: any[] = [];
  this.gridApi.forEachNode((node, index) => {
    const row = selectedRows.find(row => row.id == node.id)?.data;
    if(row){
      selectedSortedRows.push(row);
    }
  })
  console.log(selectedSortedRows);
}
```

This is not perfect because of the nested loops, I'll leave it here until a better answer is posted

Answer (score 4):

Another way could be to use [forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort](https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/accessing-data/#reference-rowNodes-forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort)

```
 getSelectedRowNodesWithSort() {
    let selectedRowNodesWithSort = [];
    this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort((node) => {
      if (node.selected) {
        selectedRowNodesWithSort.push(node);
      }
    });
    console.log(selectedRowNodesWithSort);
  }
```

Comment: I that that but is wasn't compatible with server side data